# PHP/MYSQL action on updated field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, if-statement

I am running into a slight problem, I need to generate a report that focuses on the changes on certain fields in a database. What I figured to do, is something like this

"If Updated, Insert today's date in seperate field"

that way, when I generate the report, I can verify which entries have been modified by checking the date.

Problem is, I am unsure how to do this with php/codeigniter

Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a timestamp field to your table structure

```
your_field timestamp default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
```

Take a look at the manual for the available syntax

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

edit.
If you need to update the time only if specific fields change, then you need a trigger.

```
create table test (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
field1 int,
field2 int,
field3 int,
last_update datetime)
engine = myisam;


delimiter //
drop trigger if exists update_time //
create trigger update_time before update on test
for each row begin
    if new.field2 <> old.field2 or new.field3 <> old.field3 then
        set new.last_update = now();
    end if;
end //
delimiter ;
```

in my example last_update field will be update with current time only if field2 or field3 change.

Comment: so I if understand your code correctly, PHP will know what new.field2 and old.field2 is and compare the two, and if not equal, update the time?

Comment: Php is not even involved in my answer. It's just a mysql trigger where old is the value already stored and new is new one. If they are different time field is updated.

Comment: My tables are already made, and I already have some 500 entries in it. How do I add that delimiter code?

Comment: You have to adapt the trigger code of my example to suit your needs but if you don't have any idea of what is a mysql trigger and where you have to put it, it's difficult.

Comment: Never mind, found my own answer, for another else reading this thread, check this out

http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Trigger